# JSP form sending data including files in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, get

I am tryig to send some data from jsp form to a servlet. All my data are `type="text"` except from one that is `type="file`". I know that if i want to send the data to my servlet, i have to use `request.getParameter(...)`. (My data) In order not to be null i have to use `method="get"`. But if i want to upload a file i have to use `method="post"`. How can i pass both types to my servlet using one form? Thanks in advance!

**.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="Servlet">
user:<input type="text" name="user"/>
img<input type="file" name="img"/>
</form>
```

**Servlet.java**

```
doPost(req,resp){
user = req.getParameter("user");//user == NULL
}
```

***OR***

**.jsp**

```
<form method="get" action="Servlet">
user:<input type="text"/>
img<input type="file"/>
</form>
```

**Servlet.java**

```
doGet(req,resp){
//img not passed
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    user:<input type="text" name="user"/>
    img<input type="file" name="image"/>
</form>
```

You can still get both with a post request:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    InputStream fileContent = null;
    String user = "";
    for (FileItem item : items) 
    {
        if (item.isFormField()) 
        {
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldValue = item.getString();
            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("user"))
            {
                user = fieldValue;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
            {
                fileContent = item.getInputStream();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example of how to handle `post` request with file type.

Comment: That's how i get my img. I will try it for the rest data too and i will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @ΝίκοςΔιαμαντόγιαννης no problem!